# Wires run through foundation vent screen

Tags: foundation, crawlspace

I need to replace the foundation vents in the house I recently bought. Unfortunately, AT&T, Time Warner, and others have run wires through one of the screens.

I can't easily detach the wires to run conduit. What is my best option for sealing this vent from critters?

[image]

Comment: Figure out which are still in use today and replace reroute those and eliminate the others.  It’s amazing how much of this type of cable is simply no longer in use.  Over time people change or eliminate phone carriers, isp’s, cable/satellite providers etc.  the new company installs there’s and unhooks/abandons others.  One house I saw recently the vast majority of the exterior cables were all abandoned yet the owner was meticulously reattaching and straightening rather than removing old because he didn’t know any better.

Comment: @Tyson: Good tip. I thought the AT&T guy who installed my fiber added to this mess, but it turns out that other than that bonding wire, it was all Coax that I'm not using.